# Communication between servlets and/or jsp

Tags: java

How can you sent a request from one servlet to another or one servlet to any jsp file?

Actually i want to send a request form one servlet named Demo to another jsp file abc.jsp

Comment: As you are a new user here, I would like to tell you if any answer solves your problem then you should accept the answer, so others could know what worked for you. To accept an answer you just need to click on the right tick sign on the left side of the answer below the up down arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RequestDispatcher`

programatically...

```
public class Demo extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletRespaonse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType(text/html);
        PrintWritter pr = res.getWriter();
        pr.println("i am in servlet");
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("abc.jsp");
        rd.forward();
    }
}
```

---

abc.jsp

```
<body>
<i am abc in abc.jsp>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either forward it or redirect it.

To forward, you can use [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html)

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("abc.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

To redirect,

```
response.sendRedirect("abc.jsp");
```

**FYI**, Difference between the two,

In Forwarding, the same request object is forwarded to the next resource (Servlet or JSP) and in Redirecting client (browser) is asked to send a new request to the server for the next resource (servlet or JSP).

Comment: can u please describe with an example how to invoke sendRedirect()

Comment: @DebasishDash I have also added the code in my edited answer. You just need to call sendRedirect() method by passing the parameter as of what next servlet or JSP you want to reach and you can call this method with the response object you have in your doGet or in doPost.